# Textarea input / MySQL insert / Formatted Display

Tags: php, html, mysql, format, textarea

I have an issue that I'm not sure how to solve.  Essentially, I have a textarea on my form that allows the user to enter data in this format:

```
Windows XP Home and Professional<br />(32 and 64 bit)

Windows 7 Home and Professional<br />(32 and 64 bit)
```

I can insert this into my database and retrieve/display it with no issue using nl2br in PHP.  However, I need to format the output with some HTML.  I essentially need the output to look like this in HTML:

```
<p class="smallText">Windows XP Home and Professional<br />(32 and 64 bit)</p>
<p class="smallText">Windows 7 Home and Professional<br />(32 and 64 bit)</p>
```

Essentially, when there is a single return, I need the br tag which nl2br will take care of for me.  But where there is a double return, I need to convert the br to the opening and closing p.

I would sincerely appreciate any insight someone can offer!  Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using <pre> tag and not executing the nl2br?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the text is entered correctly, and there'll be no extra spaces/blanks between the two linebreaks you're using as the paragraph indicators:

```
$txt = "Windows blah blah blah \n\n blah blah 64 bit)";
$nlbr = nl2br($txt);
$fixed = str_replace("<br /><br />", "</p><p>", $nlbr);
echo "<p>$fixed</p>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  Strange, but it still doesn't seem to be working for me.  Here is my PHP: `$SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS = nl2br($record['SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS']); $fixed = str_replace("<br /><br /><br />", "</p><p class=\"supportedPlatforms\">", $SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS); echo "<p>$fixed</p>"`  When I view the page source, I'm still seeing:  `Windows Vista Basic / Premium / Business / Enterprise / Ultimate<br />
(32 and 64 bit)<br />
<br />
<br />
Windows 7 Basic / Premium / Professional / Enterprise / Ultimate<br />
(32 and 64 bit)<br />
<br />
<br />
`

Comment: I should add that I noticed the br tags have spaces between them for some reason.  I also tried matching that in my str_replace `(ie: "<br /> <br /> <br />`  Thank you again!

Comment: Found the issue.  For some reason, I have to identify the new line in the str_replace:  `str_replace("<br />\n<br />", "</p><p>", $nlbr);` Thank you again!